# Perform transformation inside ggplot2 function to produce negative values

Tags: r, ggplot2

In respect to the below code I can produce a stacked bar chart as shown by the first graph.

```
 library(ggplot2)
 vehicle<- sample(rep(c("Cars","Cycles","Motobike"),times=c(20,50,30)))
 team<-sample(rep(c("TeamA","TeamB"),times=c(50,50)))

 df<-data.frame(team,vehicle, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

 ggplot(data = df, aes(x = as.factor (vehicle), fill =team)) +
 geom_bar(mapping = aes(y = stat(count)/sum(..count..)*100),
       position = "stack")
```

[image]

What I want to do is to produce a transformation within the `geom_bar(mapping = aes(y = stat(count)/sum(..count..)*100),position = "stack")` part that says if it is team B, then the count becomes a minus number. I want to do this so I can reproduce something like the 2nd graph.

[image]

Can anyone help amend the code to get the desired result?

Note: the second graph is created using the code below but I don't want to have to add two separate geom_bars because it means the % is incorrect on the y axis.

```
 ggplot(data = df, aes(x = as.factor (vehicle), fill =team)) +
 geom_bar(data = subset(df, team=="TeamA"),
     mapping = aes(y = stat(count)/sum(..count..)*100),
     position = "stack")+
 geom_bar(data = subset(df, team=="TeamB"),
       mapping = aes(y = - stat(count)/sum(..count..)*100),
       position = "stack") +
  labs(x = "", y="")
```

Comment: When data transformations go beyond the basics, it's usually easier and safer to use packages/functions made for data transformations (e.g,. `dplyr`, `data.table`, or base functions) rather than packages made for plotting (`ggplot2`). It's probably *possible* to do this in `ggplot`, but it's easy to do it with `dplyr` and `ggplot`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do it by using an ifelse directly in the function which achieved what I was after.

```
 set.seed (105)
 vehicle<- sample(rep(c("Cars","Cycles","Motorbike"),times=c(20,50,30)))
 team<-sample(rep(c("TeamA","TeamB"),times=c(50,50)))

 df<-data.frame(team,vehicle, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

 ggplot(data = df, aes(x = as.factor (vehicle), fill =team,
                  y= ifelse(test = team == "TeamB",
                            yes = -1/nrow(df)*100, no = 1/nrow(df)*100)))+
            geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

[image]

Comment: Beware that this will work for simple plots like you have, but not for more complicated plots (e.g., facets would break the data transformation code).

Answer (score 3):

I think it's easier to prepare the data before you feed it into `ggplot`.  I realize the numbers don't quite match up here but I'll let you deal with that.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
vehicle<- sample(rep(c("Cars","Cycles","Motobike"),times=c(20,50,30)))
team<-sample(rep(c("TeamA","TeamB"),times=c(50,50)))

df<-data.frame(team,vehicle, stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>%
  group_by(team, vehicle) %>%
  summarize(count = n()) %>%
  mutate(newcount = if_else(team == 'TeamA', count, -count))
  

ggplot(data = df, aes(x = as.factor(vehicle), y = newcount, fill =team)) +
  geom_bar(position = "stack", stat ='identity')
```

[image]